# Angular2 : Reloading routed module not fetching js and css files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am learning angular2 by doing a simple project referring [angular website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/). Dependencies are installed using npm and a lite-server is used for publishing, as in the tutorial.

Now coding everything in a single app module along with a routing module. Routing is configured as

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { 
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: 'transaction', component: TransactionFormComponent },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'transaction', pathMatch: 'full' }
      ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
])
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(success => console.log(`Bootstrap success`))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, LoginFormComponent, DashboardComponent,
                  ProfileComponent, TransactionFormComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <!-- include bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Everything works fine:**

- localhost:3000 loads login page
- Successful login loads Transaction Component by default (Now browser 
  url tab shows localhost:3000/dashboard/transaction)
- The view is rendered with styles inside style.css
- Can navigate to Profile Component.

**Except:**

On reloading localhost:3000/dashboard/transaction page by clicking browser reload button, it shows "Loading...". Browser console shows the error

```
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 17ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 12ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/systemjs.config.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 12ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 13ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 13ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]    
GET 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/systemjs.config.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]    
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

I see *localhost:3000/dashboard/..* is not the exact location.

Why this happens?

What's the solution?

On further research, met with many scenarios with no page loading. I think page is loading for me, but not js and css files. So no **Systemjs** file also, that's why page is not rendered.

Also referred [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

**Note** : added `<base href="/">` in *index.html*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to place your `<base href="/">` above the script and link tags in the `index.html`, because the browser reads from top to bottom. He first approaches the `script` and `link` tags and starts processing these. After that he finds the `base` tag, but then it's already too late and that's when the browser realises he's been an idiot for already fetching those files, but also blaming you a little for not notifying him sooner about the `base` location. Only way to fix this for you, is to help him, and place the `base` tag above any resource fetching tags.

Comment: Put `<base href="/">` above `script` tags and its simply worked. Thanks @PierreDuc